# Is there a way to round Delphi VCL Form without losing native windows borders

Tags: user-interface, delphi, user-experience, vcl

I have this repo here [DelphiUCL](https://github.com/VuioVuio/DelphiUCL)

It's very nice Lib which allow `bsSisezable` form looks like [UWP Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/forms) and What caught my attention is when I resize this form it still resizes as `bsResizable` Form and not like `bsNone` Form

What I need to know exactly:
Is there a way to create a Smooth Round Corners Delphi VCL Form without losing the native windows borders?

Comment: VCL styles were introduced in Delphi XE3 (if memory serves). Some of the styles have rounded upper corners, some have all corners rounded. Even on Windows 10. It is though unclear what Delphi version you use and what Windows version you target (if not Windows 10). Please clarify.

Comment: target os is win10 as the lib above Target Also
the target radius round corners is like 40° or above and not 10° 
if there is a property for the form or the stylemanager where i can define my custom radius for corners will be so perfect for me but vclstyles is not suport that
finaly i hope that corners be smooth (antialiassing)
thanks @TomBrunberg

Comment: this is the medium Post here:
    https://medium.com/@vuio/delphi-borderless-form-a2538e3ec48
    i think there is a workaround to achieve my request above .. but still i don't know how

Comment: You can't ask for a library recommendation here, which the [help/on-topic] guidelines say specifically. I've edited that out of your question.

Comment: thank you @KenWhite and sorry for that...

Comment: I think the answer to the specific question is no. You are asking to have two conflicting requirements simultaneously.

Comment: Native window borders are not round. Hence the answer is no.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan |   Even if there is a workaround ? for ex: like hiding the Native window borders while keeping the form bsresizable(Full Options & resize smoothly & no losing for  any option like the default shadow for ex) and keep resize the form  with this hidden native borders ....?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz | Even if there is a workaround ? for ex: like hiding the Native window borders while keeping the form bsresizable(Full Options & resize smoothly & no losing for any option like the default shadow for ex) and keep resize the form with this hidden native borders ....?

Comment: You asked the question, and we told you the answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan |  Sorry for that  .. I just trying to think out the box maybe delphi vcl form could be do it with some triks or workaround APIs (huge Respect & thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a workaround but I don't know if it will fit your need. The workaround consist of defining a rounded rectangle region to clip the window to remove title bar and border. This way, the windows is a rounded rectangle.

Then, to get back the title bar and border, you have - for example - to detect if the mouse is near one of the edges and if it is, delete the region so that title bar and borders are again visible and can be used.

All that involve handling a few messages.

Here is the code:

```
unit RegionDemoMain;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
    System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
    Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
    TRoundedForm = class(TForm)
        CloseButton: TButton;
        HelpLabel: TLabel;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure WMMouseMove(var Msg : TWMMouseMove); message WM_MOUSEMOVE;
        procedure WMNCMouseLeave(var Msg : TMessage); message WM_NCMOUSELEAVE;
        procedure WMNCButtonDown(var Msg : TWMNCLButtonDown); message WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN;
        procedure WMNCButtonUp(var Msg : TWMNCLButtonUp); message WM_NCLBUTTONUP;
        procedure WMSYSCommand(var Msg : TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
    private
        FRgnHandle       : HRGN;
        FRgnTop          : Integer;
        FRgnBottom       : Integer;
        FRgnRight        : Integer;
        FRgnLeft         : Integer;
        FRgnCorner       : Integer;
        FMouseLeaveCount : Integer;
        FNCLButtonDown   : Boolean;
        procedure DeleteRegion;
        procedure CreateRegion;
    end;

var
  RoundedForm: TRoundedForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TRoundedForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FRgnTop    := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) +
                  GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME) +
                  GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME); 
    FRgnBottom := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME) +
                  GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME);
    FRgnRight  := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME) +
                  GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME);
    FRgnLeft   := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME) +
                  GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME);
    FRgnCorner := 15;
    CreateRegion;
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.CreateRegion;
begin
    if FRgnHandle <> 0 then
        DeleteObject(FRgnHandle);
    FRgnHandle := CreateRoundRectRgn(FRgnLeft,
                                     FRgnTop,
                                     Width  - FRgnRight,
                                     Height - FRgnBottom,
                                     FRgnCorner,
                                     FRgnCorner);
    SetWindowRGN(Handle, FRgnHandle, True);
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Close;
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.DeleteRegion;
begin
    if FRgnHandle <> 0 then begin
        SetWindowRGN(Handle, 0, True);
        DeleteObject(FRgnHandle);
        FRgnHandle := 0;
    end;
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.WMMouseMove(var Msg: TWMMouseMove);
begin
    if (Msg.YPos < GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME)) or
       (Msg.YPos > (Height - 55)) or
       (Msg.XPos < 10) or
       (Msg.XPos > (Width - 25)) then
        DeleteRegion
    else if (FRgnHandle = 0) and (Msg.YPos > 10) then
        CreateRegion;
    inherited;
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.WMNCButtonDown(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDown);
begin
    FNCLButtonDown := TRUE;
    inherited;
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.WMNCButtonUp(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonUp);
begin
    FNCLButtonDown := FALSE;
    inherited;
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.WMNCMouseLeave(var Msg : TMessage);
begin
    Inc(FMouseLeaveCount);
    if (FRgnHandle = 0) and (not FNCLButtonDown) then
        CreateRegion;
    inherited;
end;

procedure TRoundedForm.WMSYSCommand(var Msg: TWMSysCommand);
begin
    if Msg.CmdType = SC_RESTORE then
        CreateRegion;
    inherited;
end;

end.
```

and DFM file:

```
object RoundedForm: TRoundedForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'RoundedForm'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object HelpLabel: TLabel
    Left = 200
    Top = 96
    Width = 222
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Move the cursor near one edge of the window'
  end
  object CloseButton: TButton
    Left = 268
    Top = 132
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'CloseButton'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = CloseButtonClick
  end
end
```

Comment: | this is exactly what i search for and i think will be so useful for solving my request above (Thank you so much)

Comment: | No it's still not complete... i Still have to find a solution to hide the native window borders while they appear .... i must find a trick to makes the native borders looks like hidden but they aren't ...

Comment: i did replace the class TForm in your code with TUForm (TRoundedForm = class(TUForm)) and works correctly but still missing the code or the trick where the native window borders can be hidden and without losing any option for the TForm like the native shadow etc ...

Comment: @Roberto You said "it is exactly what I search for" and now you want something more... I suggest you accept my answer and ask a new question with the new requirement correctly explained. Using Paint, create an image and annotate it with what you would like.

Comment: | yes it was exactly what i search for and i give you also a vote for your answer because it was usefull but not what i ask for ? (I'm so sorry for that) but my question was (Is there a way to round Delphi VCL Form without losing native windows borders)  and (I thank you once again with great respect for your concern)

Comment: @Roberto With my answer, you get a rounded corner form and the native borders are just there at hand when you comes close. If this is not what you ask, use Paint to create and annotate an image representing what you ask. Maybe you want this: With my code, change FRgnTop and FRgnLeft to 0, FRgnBottom to Height and FRgnRight to Width. The corners will be round without [completely] masking the native borders. Adjust FRgnCorner to a smaller or bigger value.

Comment: | please try your code with the library mentioned Above and use the class TUForm instead of TForm (And tell me whether it is perfect or not) ?  i need a complete solution (Your answer is very helpful and I love it very much) but still missing something that i don't know exactly..

Comment: | i'm waiting more help (sorry for that..but This is what I have been able to do or Act)